# Need to replace escape character before it is rendered in JavaScript

Tags: json

We have an input JSON embedded in an XML which is coming in as a string.
We extract the JSON from an XML object and put it in a variable.

```
{
    "maingame": {
    "day1": {
        "text1": "Tag 1",
        "text2": "Heute \" Example text\". Jeden wir.</strong> "
        }
    }
}
```

We then do JSON.parse(var) over the JSON string variable.
The \"Example text \" is read as "Example Text", which causes the JSON to break as it read the double quotes without escape characters.

We tried to replace \" with \\"  but to no avail as the \ is already used as an escape character and is not found in the string. (Confirmed that when we did indexOf("\") and it came as -1.

We need to keep the escape characters while assigning to the variables.